# Rename show per page in DataTable jQuery plugin

Tags: datatables

I have requirement to rename show per page in Data table. I'm using DataTable jQuery plugin to get feature on pagination, filtering, and sorting.

I need to change the text of show per page to be show per page (showing 500 of Total Entries)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show 500 entries before paging set "lengthMenu" in your javascript file. You can set any number of rows here to select from, e.g. 500, 700, All etc.

Here is an example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "lengthMenu": [[500], [500]]
} );
```

} );

The documentation on "lengthMenu" can be found here: https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/length_menu.html